# Google Analytics Banner Ad Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

Ok, so I'm trying to figure out if the code that I'm using for Event tracking is wrong or if there is something that I need to do inside google analytics to  make this code work.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
<a href="http://kimerwin.yourkwagent.com/" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Banner', 'Click', 'Kim Erwin']);" target="_blank"><img class="aligncenter" src="http://www.padreislandbeach.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/kw-ad.jpg" alt="kw-ad" width="620" height="160" /></a>
```

Comment: Are you using classic GA or UA? Your event code is using the GA syntax. You can also check in your real-time reports to see if events are tracking.

Comment: nyuen, I am using ua but can't find the appropriate code to change it to.  I've checked in my real-time reports and I'm not tracking.  I tried this as well but it doesn't seem to be working:

Comment: <a href="http://kimerwin.yourkwagent.com/" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Banner', 'Click', Kim Erwin);" target="_blank"><img class="aligncenter" src="http://www.padreislandbeach.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/kw-ad.jpg" alt="kw-ad" width="620" height="160" /></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For UA event tracking, the syntax should be:

```
onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Banner', 'Click', 'Kim Erwin');"
```